# My C++ mpi code doesn't finish it's run times ..it stucks at the 27th run?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on ABC algorithm using MPI to optimize Rastrigin function. My code's structure goes as follows:

1. I defined the control parameters
2. I defined my variables and arrays
3. I wrote my functions.
4. and called them back in a for loop right in my main.

and here is the my main in which I think my problem is at, I have defined total run times of 30 but when I run it get stuck on the 27th run. I'm running it on 4 nodes but it gets stuck! Any help?

Here is my main code :

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int iter,run,j;
    double mean;
    mean=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank); 
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProc); 
    for(run=0;run<runtime;run++)
    {
        if(myRank==0){
            initial();
            MemorizeBestSource();
        }

        for (iter=0;iter<maxCycle;iter++)
        {
            SendEmployedBees();
            if(myRank==0){
                CalculateProbabilities();
                SendOnlookerBees();
                MemorizeBestSource();
                SendScoutBees();
            }
        }
        if(myRank==master){
            for(j=0;j<D;j++)
                printf("GlobalParam[%d]: %f\n",j+1,GlobalParams[j]);
            printf("%d. run: %e \n",run+1,GlobalMin);
            GlobalMins[run]=GlobalMin;
            mean=mean+GlobalMin;
        }
    }
    if(myRank==master){
        mean=mean/runtime;
        printf("Means of %d runs: %e\n",runtime,mean);

        getch();
        MPI_Finalize ();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of undeclared variables in the code so it doesn't compile

Comment: @TomFenech this is not the whole code ..this is just the main ...i didn't post the whole code in where but everything is defined ..can i send it to you somewhere else ?

Comment: It would be useful to have a minimal example that compiles and reproduces your problem - this will probably help you to debug it too.